# Cordova build and gradle dependencies

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

Well, a project that worked like a charm during time.

After update multiple parts of the full stack:

- Npm
- Node
- Cordova
- Android

Now, running: `cordova build`

returns the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
 Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApk'.
    A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
       Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
          Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2.
           Searched in the following locations:
               https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.pom
               https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.jar
           Required by:
               android:CordovaLib:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Of course I've tried the "Try" with no success.

The "funny" part, Android studio can build with no problems.
I can also paste the gradle file if required.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you try reinstalling latest Cordova once rather than updating?

Comment: @Gandhi, quite accurate to the actual solution, I'll paste as a solution right away

Comment: Glad it worked. Have posted my answer based on my experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, sorry for adding noise in StackOverflow, but, after reading TONS of questions and answers in here, I couldn't still solve it.

So I've applied the old Spanish saying: To stop the rage, kill the dog.

So I've uninstalled the Android platform with:

```
cordova platforms remove android
```

Note: risky movement, so if you do so, **first copy your files in platforms!**

And I've reinstalled prying it would be solved with:

```
cordova platforms add android
```

And you know what? 
Sometimes prays have compensation!

Everything started working like a charm -_-

I can understand what is the error, and some solutions I've found around like downloading the dependency and referring to it locally.

But sincerely, I don't consider that a good solution. Mainly because then... what is the point of having repositories and dependency managers?

What I consider quite unacceptable is how this can happen. There is something really wrong in the Cordova stack.

Anyhow, so far fixed lesson learned, Cordova projects are fragile and difficult to maintain. Really difficult.

**Disclaimer**: I'm not religious and, even more important, I'm totally against any kind of agression/attack/etc. against animals. Don't interpretate wrong the expressions I've used more for fun than enything else.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Generally such problems could be due to some file corruption in Cordova framework or android platform folder.

Removing and re-adding platform fixes the issues most of the times. If it dint work out, reinstalling Cordova rather than updating it fixes the issue. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution on windows: remove this directory if it says that your gradle or some other lib is not found,

```
c:\Users\YourUserName\.gradle\caches\
```

then go to your project's dir in command prompt and run

```
cordova build android
```

Cordova will download them for you and reload `\caches` directory and it's contents.

Then you'll probably will be asked to install needed Android SDK API(if so open Andorid SDK manager as usuall and install API SDK level asked by Cordova) and you'll get a successfull build.